# How to process fixed length file using copy command in Snowflake

Tags: copy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a positional based file,

I have used the below command

```
Copy into <table_name>


From <snowflake stage>

File format = (Type= Fixed Field_positions = (1,4,21,34)

Field_Names = (Field_1,Field_2,Field_3,Field_4))

On_error = 'Continue'

Validation_mode = Return_all_errors;
```

Getting below issue:

001008 (22023): SQL compilation error:
Invalid value [Fixed] for parameter 'Type'

Expectation is, i want to process fixed length format file using copy command with Validation _mode

Comment: Hi - when you read the documentation for the COPY INTO statement, where did you get the idea that processing fixed field length files was possible? Where is this in the allowable file format types?

Comment: You should be able to read the whole line as a string, and then parse it within the `COPY + SELECT` command

Comment: Thanks for your response @ Felipe Hoffa, Yes I did the same way, I mean I have load the entire data into a table which has only one field having varchar(max) length then I have applied the substr based on positions in the insert statement in the same copy only, please see my below answer for more details

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response @ Felipe Hoffa,
Yes I did the same way, I mean I have load the entire data into a table which has only one field having varchar(max) length then I have applied the sustr based on positions in the insert statement in the same copy only,

```
Copy into <tmp_table>
From <Snowflake stage>
File format= (type =CSV 
record_delimiter'\n' 
filed_opionslly_enclosed_by='')
```

Insert into <Final_table>
(filed_1,filed_2...)
Select filed_1,filed_2 ....
From <tmo_tsble>

`
Using this approach i am un able to apply the validation mode while loading data from Snowflake stage to tmp_table

Is there any way to handle the bad records using validaion_mode=retrun_all_errors for positional file

Thank you in advance...!

Comment: Please include any additional details or follow-ups directly to the question by [editting](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77133472/edit), not as an answer.